# django-channels/celery: how to track progress of a list of tasks?

Tags: django, celery, django-channels

I'm "successfully" sending a message from the view to the client with the status of a group of tasks (not an actual celery group). The problem is: This really ignores whether all tasks are actually performed. I've attempted to add a callback (`task.apply_async(link=)`) but that didn't help either.

The tasks themselves don't really take a lot of time, but I'd really like to be able to increment the counter when the task has actually been performed:

```
if 'selected' in request.GET:
        selected_as_list = request.GET.getlist('selected')
        print(selected_as_list)
        searches = list(set([s.strip() for s in selected_as_list if s.strip()]))
        task_group = [refresh_func.s(str(user_profile.id), search, dont_auto_add=True) for search in searches]

        for i,task in enumerate(task_group):
            task.apply_async()
            Group(str(request.user.id)).send({"text": json.dumps({"tasks_completed": i+1,
                                                                  "task_id": "fb_import",
                                                                  "completed": True if i == len(task_group) -1 else False,
"total": len(task_group)})})
```

So I moved the code out of the view, and into the same block that actually calls the operation to be done. Though it meant I was passing many parameters now, this solved the initial problem. But it presents another one: A task with an index of "1" can finish after a task with an index "3", and this obviously updates the counter incorrectly.

What can be done to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

How about spawning a background thread that periodically checks the status of the spawned tasks (you can get those statuses if you know the tasks' IDs)?

This thread should be run in the Django server (not in the Celery tasks) because that's probably where your `django-channel` is active: If you call `Group(...).send` in the task, it will probably not be able to access it (specially since *usually* celery workers run in separate processes/machines)

Let's say you spawn tasks in a `.GET` implementation of a view. Maybe you could collect the tasks ids there (where they're spawned) and periodically check their status in a thread (so you don't block the `.GET` response).

Let's say the view where you spawn your tasks looks like this:

```
class Test(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'stack_092.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("Yep")
        task_group = [foo_task.s(i) for i in range(5)]
        logger.info("Task signatures created: %s", task_group)

        task_ids = [task.apply_async().task_id for task in task_group]
        logger.info("Tasks launched")
        th = threading.Thread(target=verify_task_ids, args=('request.user.id', task_ids))
        th.start()
        logger.info("Thread started")
        return super(Test, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And something like this could be the `verify_task_ids` target function for the Thread:

```
def verify_task_ids(channel_group_id, task_ids):
    previous_finished_task_ids = set()
    finished_task_ids = set()
    logger.info("Verifying %s task_ids", len(task_ids))
    while len(finished_task_ids) < len(task_ids):
        finished_task_ids = set()
        for task_id in task_ids:
            if AsyncResult(task_id).ready():
                finished_task_ids.add(task_id)
        if finished_task_ids != previous_finished_task_ids:
            logger.info("%s new finished tasks", 
                        len(finished_task_ids) - len(previous_finished_task_ids))
        previous_finished_task_ids = finished_task_ids
```

In the example, the `channel_group_id` argument is just a pure hardcoded string `"request.user.id"`. In your case you should substitute it by the actual `request.user.id` of the user that is logged into the server, since that is your group ID.

And you will see that when a new task is finished, I only show a log message:

```
if finished_task_ids != previous_finished_task_ids:
        logger.info("%s new finished tasks", 
                    len(finished_task_ids) - len(previous_finished_task_ids))
```

Here's where instead of the `logger.info` function you should probably call

```
if finished_task_ids != previous_finished_task_ids:
    Group(
        str(channel_group_id)
    ).send(
        {
            "text": json.dumps({
                "tasks_completed": len(finished_task_ids),
                "task_id": "fb_import",
                "completed": len(finished_task_ids) == len(task_ids),
             })
         }
     )
```

I don't know much (erm... anything, rather... about django-channels) so I'm not sure this solution will work, but maybe it's worth a try?

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to avoid polling. Maybe I can adopt parts of your answer and somehow check for this inside a for loop somewhere while the tasks are still running.

Comment: I imagined **:(** The main issue (for me at least) is that the Celery workers tend to run in different servers than the web server. Even if not, they do run in separate processes, which makes communication with the process that created it rather difficult. Good luck with it, though, and if you get it solved by yourself, could you add what you did as an answer to your own question? It's something that interests me as well.

Comment: I actually managed to do it earlier today. It’s very clunky and barely readable at the moment, and also seems to be a bit spammy, but it is “asynchronous”. I’ll post the answer once I get it refactored, but here’s the general idea: gather function signatures, send as list to a helper function, there, in a for loop, do `task.freeze()` and append each task ID to a list, then, start an async task which iterates through this list until all IDs’ states return “SUCCESS”(this sends messages through channels). Only then, do task.apply_async() in a similar for loop.

Comment: I’m pretty even polling is better than this. But I had to solve this challenge.